# Change Default Image Viewer in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

The default image viewing software changed for one of my Outlook 2007 users. I presume it was previously the Default Windows XP Image and Fax viewer and now it is the MS Office Picture Manager. How can I change this back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing default programs in XP or earlier

•1
Right click on an image file, then select the "Open With" option.

•2
Select the application that you want to use as your default picture viewer.

•3
Choose to "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file."

•4
Click the "OK" button.

•5
Repeat this process for any new picture file type that does not open with the correct application.

Taken from: [How to Change a Default Picture Viewer With Outlook](http://www.ehow.com/how_5911641_change-default-picture-viewer-outlook.html) | eHow.com